# Get a string from a string element

Tags: c++, string, stl

I am newbie in C++. I have a question that how can I get a string from a string element(one element or character).
Like, I have a `std::string` named `h` and it contains `"HKK"`. Now I have another string named `k`. Now I want to get the element number 1(k) from `h` and set it to `k`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   string h = "HKK";
   string k = h.at(1); //K
   cout << k << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

But the compiler(g++) gives error that :

```
 error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
 string k = h.at(1);
                  ^
```

**edit:**
If I do it for a function like:

```
void out(string out) {
   cout << "Out : " << out << endl;
}

int main() {
   string h = "HKK";
   out(h.at(1)); //K
   return 0;
}
```

Is there any solution than this?

```
string k += h.at(1);
out(k);
```

Please help me!
Thanks
Sorry for bad English

Comment: [`std::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) rather than `at()`.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I get a string from a string element(one element or character). Like, I have a `std::string` named `h` and it contains "HKK"

either you use `std::string::at`:

```
std::string h = "HKK";
std::string k;
k += h.at(1); //K
```

or you use `std::string::operator[]`:

```
k += h[1];
```

> Now I have another `string` named `k`. Now I want to get the element number 1(k) from `h` and set it to 'k'.

either you use `std::string::replace`:

```
std::string k = "HkK";
k.replace( 1, 1, "k" );
```

or you use `std::string::operator[]`:

```
k[1] = 'k';
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I personally don't like your `function` calling still I'm providing the solution to it which goes as follows :-

```
void out(string out) 
{
   cout << "Out : " << out << endl;
}

int main() 
{
   string h = "HKK";
   out(string().append(1,h.at(1))); //K
   return 0;
}
```

Here you create a temporary `string` variable with `string()` & `append` 1 character to it (ie `h.at(1)` in your case). Hence `out` which is a string in your function `out` has only one value ie `K`.

However I will always recommend you to use a `non-temporary` rather than a temporary as in this case. They are much safer & less prone to errors.

Comment: None of those will compile if used as replacement for the line marked `//K`. It would be good to expand your answer to show complete replacement for that line.

Comment: you can also use `string("").append({h.at(1)})`